# Tomcat stuck on `Deployment will start in few seconds`

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, deployment, console

When sometimes I close my Tomcat and delete my `Temp and Work` folders and redeploy my application and start the Tomcat again. It stops on this message in console.

`Deployment will start in few seconds` Why ??

Even if I redeploy again it stops at the same location.

Any key strike or mouse click also doesn't release the console either.

Why is my deployment not completing?

Comment: Does it do that for any application or for a specific one?

Comment: @cherouvim some specific applications. Mostly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution was by deleting the xml file within the `conf` folder.

Then the deployment continued. This may help a few, but not a sure shot solution I guess.